# Writing a program to find sum of a series using math.pow and math.factorial

Tags: python, loops, math, series, factorial

Here is the question my teacher gave us:

> Write a program to find the sum of the following series (accept values of x and n from user). Use functions of the math library like math.pow and math.factorial:
> 1 + x/1! + x2/2! + ……….xn/n!

This is the code I've come up with. I calculated it on paper with simple numbers and there's clearly some logic errors because I can't get a correct answer. I think I've been looking at it for too long to really grasp the issue, so I could use some help.

```
import math
x = int(input ("Input x: "))
n = int(input("Input n: "))
for i in range (n):
  power = math.pow(x,i)
  ans = 1 + (power / math.factorial(i))
print(ans)
```

Note: This is an entry level class, so if there's an easier way to do this with a specific function or something I can't really use it because I haven't been taught it yet, although appreciate any input!

Comment: It's because your ans variable being reassigned completely each time instead of accumulating the result.

Comment: Are you explicitly told to use `math.pow` and `math.factorial`?

Comment: `ans = 1 +...`-> `ans = ans +...`?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using those functions.  There are better ways to do it that are within the grasp of entry level programmers.

Here's what I recommend you try:

```
import math

x = int(input ("Input x: "))
n = int(input("Input n: "))
sum = 1
term = 1.0
for i in range (1,n+1):
  term *= x/i
  sum += term

print(sum)
```

You don't need those functions.  They're inefficient for this case.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling they were inefficient since I could think of ways to at least attempt it without using the functions. But the teacher put it in the instructions, so unfortunately I have to do it that way. Thanks for your input though, I'll keep that in mind for when I have less restrictive questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work for you:

```
import math

x = int(input ("Input x: "))
n = int(input("Input n: "))
ans = 1
for i in range (1,n+1):
  power = math.pow(x,i)
  ans += (power / math.factorial(i))

print(ans)
```

We start the ans variable at 1 and we add the new term to ans through each iteration of the loop. Note that `x+=n` is the same as `x=x+n` for integers.

I also changed the range that your loop is going through, since you start at 1 and go up to n, rather than starting at 0 and going to n-1.

Output:

```
Input x: 2
Input n: 5
7.266666666666667
```

For people familiar with the mathematical constant e:

```
Input x: 1
Input n: 15
2.718281828458995
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ans` only includes (the 1 and) the latest term. You should instead Initialize it before the loop and then add all the terms to it. The first term 1 doesn't deserve ugly special treatment, so I compute it like all the others instead:

```
import math
x = int(input ("Input x: "))
n = int(input("Input n: "))
ans = 0
for i in range(n + 1):
    ans += math.pow(x, i) / math.factorial(i)
print(ans)
```

And a preview how you'll likely soon be taught/allowed to write it:

```
import math
x = int(input ("Input x: "))
n = int(input("Input n: "))
print(sum(math.pow(x, i) / math.factorial(i)
          for i in range(n + 1)))
```

Comment: I see, thanks for including the efficient way as well!